# Selecting multiple count with different conditions from same table mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, stored-functions

I have a table like below

tbl_test

```
test_id     name    val

1            ab       1
2            ac       1
3            ad       2
4            af       3
5            fg       2
6            ss       1
7            dd       3
```

I want count of name according to val in same query

tried

```
(select count(name )   where val='1' ) as one,
(select count(name )   where val='2' ) as two,
(select count(name )   where val='3' ) as thr
```

Expected output

```html
one  two  thr

3     2   2
```

Comment: Please add your expected output. AND read up on mysql aggregate functions.

Comment: Is the max value for VAL can only be 3?

Comment: yes the maximum value is 3@Ankit Bajpai

Comment: Why a stored procedure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use conditional aggregation with `case when expression` -

```
select 
    count(case when val=1 then name end) as one,
    count(case when val=2 then name end) as two,
    count(case when val=3 then name end) as thr
from tbl_test
```